# NumPy loadtxt load every other column

Tags: python, numpy

I have an `ASCII` file containing a large number of columns and I'd like to load only every other column (skip first, load second, skip third, load fourth, etc.).

Is there a way to do that with `numpy.loadtxt`, except for using `usecols=(2,4,6,...)`?

Comment: What's wrong with `usecols`? If it's just how many columns you'd have to write out, don't forget you can do `usecols=xrange(1, numcols, 2)`. (Also, don't forget that columns start from 0.)

Comment: Ah, that clears it. I wasn't aware that I can use xrange as a input for usecols. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to write out a giant tuple of even or odd numbers; you can have Python do that for you:

```
data = numpy.loadtxt(..., usecols=xrange(1, numcols, 2))
```

I've passed an xrange here, since the usecols parameter can be any sequence type, but even if you needed a tuple, you could just call `tuple`:

```
data = numpy.loadtxt(..., usecols=tuple(xrange(1, numcols, 2)))
```